# where is install_name_tool for Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: xcode, macos, install-name-tool

I had installed command line tools when I installed Xcode 5 in my mac. 
`install_name_tool` was working fine back then.

Now, When I try to use `install_name_tool` I get following error,  `malformed object (unknown load command 4)`
Upon googling I found out that this error is due to the command line tools are not updated along with OS or Xcode. So i went here (https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) downloaded the command line tools for 10.9, and tried again on terminal, but the error persisted.

Then I tried updating my Xcode from 5-->5.1.1, went to `Downloads` in preferences, there was no option to download the command line tools. I installed the pkg which I downloaded earlier for command line tools, I am still getting the same error.

install_name_tools doesnt exist in this director, as one of the answers on other similar questions suggested--- > `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/`

My question, where does the `install_name_tool` gets installed after installing it from a pkg?

Comment: What does `install_name_tool --help` say?

Comment: Open Xcode package and look for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool

Comment: `Usage: install_name_tool [-change old new] ... [-id name] input`

that tells me that its installed. when i use `type -a install_name_tool`  I get installed location as-- `install_name_tool is /usr/bin/install_name_tool`

Comment: But before "Usage" it doesn't show you the real path to `install_name_tool` that I showed above?

Comment: I do see `install_name_tools` inside the Xcode package in the path you mentioned, I changed my dir to that dir, and tried using install_name_tool like i always do, i still get the error

Comment: No, it doesnt show the real path that you mentioned

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52408/discussion-between-2am-and-matt)

Comment: Also `xcrun --find install_name_tool` should find it inside Xcode in that same place.

Comment: yes, `xcrun --find install_name_tool` found it inside the Xcode.app, so why the same error? :(

Comment: This thread (which you've probably seen) suggests that you may need to reinstall the system: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/25665

Comment: Yes, that is my last resort :) anyhow thanks will post what happens.